# Converting HQL to SQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I wanted to know how can we convert a HQL query into a sql query .I know if we make the showsql = true parameter on we can get the sql query but the parameter value would not be appended with its values .I need to find ways to print the SQL query generated in logs and use for my performance optimization .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know that you can print the parameters of the prepared statements? I am not sure you will able to show the entire queries (with bound parameters) in a clean way.

Answer (score 5):

You can check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37749916/1350643

In short you can use following code to convert hql to sql:

```
QueryTranslatorFactory translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) getSessionFactory();
QueryTranslator translator = translatorFactory.
        createQueryTranslator(hqlQueryText, hqlQueryText, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, factory);
translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
translator.getSQLString();
```

Source: http://narcanti.keyboardsamurais.de/hibernate-hql-to-sql-translation.html

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate uses [dialects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/session-configuration.html#configuration-optional-dialects) for specific optimizations. Maybe you could extend one of the existing Oracle dialects or supply your own.You can create your custom dialect by subclassing the Oracle dialect.