# How to convert HQL to SQL Query programmatically (without logging)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql, jpql

I am executing the following HQL and it is executing properly

```
String hql = "FROM Employee";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
List results = query.list();
```

Now, I also want to log the sql generated at the backend in logs for support users.

I want to make use of QueryTranslator please advise how can I generate the sql for the corresponding HQL please advise how to achieve this.

Answer (score 9):

You can use hibernate QueryTranslator:

```
String hqlQueryString = hqlQuery.getQueryString();
ASTQueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
SessionImplementor hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator("", hqlQueryString, java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, hibernateSession.getFactory());
queryTranslator.compile(java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
String sqlQueryString = queryTranslator.getSQLString();
```

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working for Hibernate 5 :( There is new 5th parameter `EntityGraphQueryHint`.

Comment: you can pass null as the 5th parameter. It should work.

Comment: This only returns the hql not the sql; the question was: "Now i also want to log the sql generated at the backend in logs for support users "

Comment: The code finally returns SQL equivalence of hqlQuery in "sqlQueryString" variable.

Comment: Unfortunately the aliases of the columns are not used.

Comment: How did you get the entityManager variable?

Comment: Depending on your spring and jpa config, it has different approaches. in a nutshell, first define "@PersistenceContext EntityManager entityManager;" property in your bean class,then add tx:annotation-driven to your .xml configuration, and finally mark your methods where you use entityManager as @Transactional.

Comment: Unfortunatelly this whole approach is nonexistent on hibernate 6

Answer (score 6):

I believe you want a combination of the top 2 answers

```
  String hqlQueryString = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
  ASTQueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
  SessionImplementor hibernateSession = em.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
  QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator("", hqlQueryString, java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, hibernateSession.getFactory());
  queryTranslator.compile(java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
  String sqlQueryString = queryTranslator.getSQLString();
```

Comment: createQueryTranslator requires one more parameter: **EntityGraphQueryHint**.

Comment: After translating, all the parameters like ":variable" where replaced by "?", and I can't set parameters values.
I've also tried to set parameters, then translating it to SQL, but it didn't worked as well.
Note: I'm doing this to append it as subquery of a count, because of the many parameters inside group by, and HQL does not support this

Comment: non existing since hibernate 6 if anybody wants to try it out

Answer (score 3):

I found next solution on the web:

```
QueryTranslatorFactory translatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
SessionFactoryImplementor factory = (SessionFactoryImplementor) getSessionFactory();
QueryTranslator translator = translatorFactory.
        createQueryTranslator(hqlQueryText, hqlQueryText, Collections.EMPTY_MAP, factory);
translator.compile(Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
translator.getSQLString();
```

Source: http://narcanti.keyboardsamurais.de/hibernate-hql-to-sql-translation.html

Comment: non existing since hibernate 6 if anybody wants to try it out

Answer (score 3):

This is also possible with TypedQuery in later versions of Hibernate using the following code

```
String hqlQueryString=typedQuery.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).getQueryString();
        ASTQueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
        SessionImplementor hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
        QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator("", hqlQueryString, java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, hibernateSession.getFactory(), null);
        queryTranslator.compile(java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
        String sqlQueryString = queryTranslator.getSQLString();
```

Answer (score 2):

This works, other answers have a problem for modern versions of hibernate:

```
String hqlQueryString = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
ASTQueryTranslatorFactory queryTranslatorFactory = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory();
SessionImplementor hibernateSession = entityManager.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
QueryTranslator queryTranslator = queryTranslatorFactory.createQueryTranslator("", hqlQueryString, java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, hibernateSession.getFactory(), null);
queryTranslator.compile(java.util.Collections.EMPTY_MAP, false);
String sqlQueryString = queryTranslator.getSQLString();
```

Comment: This worked today for me... There seem to be a few versions of this problem flying around...

Answer (score 2):

### Hibernate Types

Starting with the 2.9.11 version, the [Hibernate Types](https://github.com/vladmihalcea/hibernate-types) open-source project offers the `SQLExtractor` utility that allows you to get the SQL query from any JPQL or Criteria API query, no matter you are using Hibernate 5.4, 5.3, 5.2, 5.1, 5.0, 4.3, 4.2, or 4.1.

### Get the SQL statement from a JPQL (HQL) Query

Let's assume we have the following JPQL (HQL) query:

```
Query jpql = entityManager.createQuery("""
    select 
       YEAR(p.createdOn) as year, 
       count(p) as postCount 
    from 
       Post p 
    group by 
       YEAR(p.createdOn)
    """, Tuple.class
);
```

With Hibernate Types, extracting the Hibernate-generated SQL query is as simple as that:

```
String sql = SQLExtractor.from(jpql);
```

And, if we log the extracted SQL query:

```
LOGGER.info("""
    The JPQL query: [
        {}
    ]
    generates the following SQL query: [ 
        {}
    ]
    """,
    jpql.unwrap(org.hibernate.query.Query.class).getQueryString(),
    sql
);
```

We get the following output:

```
- The JPQL query: [
    select    
        YEAR(p.createdOn) as year,    
        count(p) as postCount 
    from    
        Post p 
    group by    
        YEAR(p.createdOn)
]
generates the following SQL query: [
    SELECT 
        extract(YEAR FROM sqlextract0_.created_on) AS col_0_0_,
        count(sqlextract0_.id) AS col_1_0_
    FROM 
        post p
    GROUP BY 
        extract(YEAR FROM p.created_on)
]
```

> Notice that we unwrapped the JPQL (HQL) `Query` to the Hibernate `org.hibernate.query.Query` interface which provided the `getQueryString` method we can use to log the associated JPQL query string.

Comment: Why do the SQL "AS" clauses contain junk? Is there some way to get the SQL with the same aliases as the JPQL?

Comment: Until Hibernate 6, the JDBC columns were read by name, not by their position. Therefore, Hibernate 5 uses unique column aliases, and that's why they are auto-generated. Hibernate 6 switched to position-based column referencing, so column aliases are no longer needed there. The only way to avoid the column aliases is to execute the native SQL query exactly as you want it to be. In Hibernate 5, JPQL will always be parsed to an SQL query that uses unique column aliases.

Comment: I'm not sure I've understood your point about Hibernate 6. Are you saying I get the real SQL with Hibernate 6, no name mangling? I'm really not sure what the purpose of a mangled SQL query is. Post -> post,  createdOn -> created_on. And I've no idea what sqlextract0_ is.

Answer (score 0):

When upgrading to Hibernate 6 following code stopped compiling (which is suggested as fix for the issue with versions prior to 6)

```
public static String extractNativeSql(String hql, EntityManager em) {
    QueryTranslator queryTranslator = new ASTQueryTranslatorFactory().createQueryTranslator(
            EMPTY, hql, EMPTY_MAP, em.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class).getFactory(), null
    );
    queryTranslator.compile(EMPTY_MAP, false);
    return queryTranslator.getSQLString();
}
```

because those classes no longer exist.

I managed to get it working with

```
public static String extractNativeSql(String hql, EntityManager em) {
    var session = em.unwrap(SessionImplementor.class);
    return SQLExtractor.from(session.createQuery(hql));
}
```

Since I was using spring-boot-dependencies 3.1.5 which uses hibernate 6.2.13 I had to add the following dependency for SQLExtractor

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.hypersistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>hypersistence-utils-hibernate-62</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score -3):

you can get the Query out by using the unwrap method.

```
String queryString = query.unwrap(org.hibernate.Query.class).getQueryString();
```

Comment: what version of hibernate has a query with an unwrap method?

Comment: part of java6 persistence api
https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/Query.html

Comment: This only works to get the HQL query and not the SQL query

Comment: This is only to get the HQL and not the resulting SQL